# Samsung Galaxy loosing mobile network connection randomly until restart

Tags: samsung, sim-card, mobile-network

I'm using a `Samsung Galaxy S20 FE 4G` and every time I enter a building's basement, even for just a short time period, the connection is cut and my phone looses it's connection to the mobile network.

(Sometimes it also just happens randomly and I only notice it once a song stops playing in the background).

I can still connect to WI-FI, but the 4 bars disappear and I'm not receiving any signal/connection, until I completely restart my phone or take out my SIM-card and put it in again, which probably restarts the SIM-driver.

Is it possible to manually restart the SIM-driver, which does not require me to restart my phone, nor take out my SIM-card?

(And is there an answer to why my phone is even doing this in the first place?)

Thank you very much!

Comment: The only action you can do is enable Airplane mode and some seconds later disable it.

Comment: @Robert wouldn't de- and activating mobile data do the same? Because that does not work.

Comment: Just deactivating mobile data does only disabled the data channel on cellular level but the voice part remains active. Therefore enabling Airplane mode should make a difference.

Comment: @Robert Thank you very much for the explanation! Next time it happens, I'll let you know if it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Original solution by [@Robert](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/2241/robert).

I'm just answering my own question, so other people facing the same problem, know that there is, in fact, a solution.

`Just activate "airplane mode" for a few seconds and then deactivate it again`, in order to not just disable mobile network, but also 'the voice part'.